# how to give scroll to tbody of a table in datatables.js

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using datatables plugin for my table,In that i want to provide scroll option only to tbody so that thead keeps fixed.Currently i am giving scroll option to div that contains table which is not efficient way.
After initializing datatable,i tried to change the tbody css property but it wont work and also i tried scrollY    parameter of datatable but nothing use.

Any idea how to do this?

jquery

```
      var oTable = $('#tbcont').dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bAutoWidth": false,                
            "bFilter": true,
            "scrollY": "100px",
            "scrollCollapse":true,
            "paging":false
         });
```

Comment: give "tbody" something like overflow-y:auto and overflow-x:hidden in your css

Comment: I tried it wont work.

Comment: did you do something like this :-  #tbcont tbody{overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto;}

Comment: yah but the problem is in tbody height so overflow not reflects.

Comment: set the height of tbody , unless overflow won't work and don't set height:auto as not setting any height and setting height auto are same . So please set some height to your tbody . I hope it would work

Answer (score 1):

You should use the FixedHeader extension: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/.

Comment: I tried,it goes to top of page normally,when change position property to absolute it is some what k but not exact what i want.

Comment: i want like in below link http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to answer this question myself lately, this answer is for general tables not datatables if you want to apply the below approach we need to change **thead td** to **thead td div**

below is the jsfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/v2t2k8ke/2/

HTML:

```
<table border='1' id='tbl_cnt'>
<thead><tr></tr></thead><tbody></tbody>
```

CSS:

```
 #tbl_cnt{
 border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;word-break:break-all;
 }
 #tbl_cnt thead, #tbl_cnt tbody{
 display: block;
 }
 #tbl_cnt thead tr{
 background-color: #8C8787; text-align: center;width:100%;display:block;
 }
 #tbl_cnt tbody {
 height: 100px;overflow-y: auto;overflow-x: hidden;
 }
```

Jquery:

```
 var data = [
    {
    "status":"moving","vehno":"tr544","loc":"bng","dri":"ttt"
    }, {
    "status":"stop","vehno":"tr54","loc":"che", "dri":"ttt"
    },{    "status":"idle","vehno":"yy5499999999999994","loc":"bng","dri":"ttt"
    },{
    "status":"moving","vehno":"tr544","loc":"bng", "dri":"ttt"
    }, {
    "status":"stop","vehno":"tr54","loc":"che","dri":"ttt"
    },{
    "status":"idle","vehno":"yy544","loc":"bng","dri":"ttt"
    }
    ];
   var sth = '';
   $.each(data[0], function (key, value) {
     sth += '<td>' + key + '</td>';
   });
   var stb = '';        
   $.each(data, function (key, value) {
       stb += '<tr>';
       $.each(value, function (key, value) {
       stb += '<td>' + value + '</td>';
       });
       stb += '</tr>';
    });
      $('#tbl_cnt thead tr').append(sth);
      $('#tbl_cnt tbody').append(stb);
      setTimeout(function () {
      var col_cnt=0 
      $.each(data[0], function (key, value) {col_cnt++;});    
      $('#tbl_cnt thead tr').css('width', ($("#tbl_cnt tbody") [0].scrollWidth)+ 'px');
      $('#tbl_cnt thead tr td,#tbl_cnt tbody tr td').css('width',  ($('#tbl_cnt thead tr ').width()/Number(col_cnt)) + 'px');}, 100)
```